# Поочередная запись потоками в файл

Tags: java, файлы, concurrency

Всем привет, есть задание:
На вход передается целое число, больше 0, кратное 2 (n). Создается два потока, работающих
параллельно, каждый поток в цикле, считывает значение из файла out.txt увеличивает
его на 1, выводит в консоли старое значение, новое значение и идентификатор потока
(идентификатор может быть произвольным), и записывает обратно в файл.
В конечном итоге оба потока должны успешно завершить свою работу, и в консоль
должно вывестись содержимое файла out.txt (которое должно быть равно заданному
на входе n).
Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
private static final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

public void execute() {
    threadOne.start();
    threadTwo.start();
} 

private void task() {
    try {
        semaphore.acquire();
        while (incrementValue()) {
            incrementValue();
            semaphore.release();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private boolean incrementValue() {
    try {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileReader(FILE_NAME));
        int value = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        if (value == n) {
            return false;
        }
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(FILE_NAME);
        writer.write(String.valueOf(value + 1));
        System.out.printf("Thread: %s, old - %d, new - %d", Thread.currentThread().getName(), value, ++value);
        System.out.println();
        writer.flush();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

#### В итоге на выходе получается это:

Thread: Thread-0, old - 0, new - 1
Thread: Thread-0, old - 1, new - 2
Thread: Thread-0, old - 2, new - 3
Thread: Thread-1, old - 2, new - 3
Thread: Thread-0, old - 3, new - 4
Thread: Thread-1, old - 3, new - 4

Как сделать так, чтобы потоки поочередно записывали в файл? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сразу целая куча проблем:

1. семафор захватываете перед циклом, а отпускаете внутри. После первой итерации семафор отпущен, а поток продолжает себе работать с файлом. Нужно захватывать один раз в начале тела цикла.
2. За одну итерацию метод `incrementValue` вызывается два раза. Сначала в условии цикла `while` и еще раз в теле. Делайте раз в теле и присваивайте переменной, которую и проверяйте в условии.
3. Файлу после записи нужно не просто `flush` делать, а полностью закрывать. Пользуйтесь [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Вот так (плюс изменения по работе с файлами) работает лучше:

```
boolean toContinue = true;
while (toContinue) {
    semaphore.acquire();
    toContinue = incrementValue();
    semaphore.release();
    Thread.sleep(1);  // см. пояснения ниже 
}
```

Строка с `sleep` необязательна, но дело в том, что после отпускания семафора JVM необязательно отдаст управление другому потоку. Переключение между потоками довольно накладная операция и поэтому слишком часто JVM ее не делает. При малых значениях `n` квант времени выделенный для выполнения первому потоку может и не завершиться и тогда он опять захватит семафор. На моей системе один поток успевает сделать около 200 переключений, пока планировщик не отдаст управление другому потоку (это если без `sleep`). `sleep` же (немного) уравнивает шансы, т.е. это сигнал планировщику, что данный поток хочет отдать управление. (Также можно использовать `Thread.yield()` или `Thread.sleep(0)`, но с ними тот же поток чаще продолжает выполнение по крайне мере у меня на системе).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Понял, что нужен CyclicBarrier, но куда его впихнуть?

Comment: Сейчас вижу, что я слишком буквально воспринял слово `поочередно`. В условии нет такого, что именно строго поочередно, так что достаточно исправить проблемы перечисленные в ответе (подправил).

Comment: Не помогло, захватываю в цикле, вызываю метод, отхватываю. Но все равно получается в одном потоке

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Заработало как нужно, спасибо!